# Magento: How can we override Enterprise files (Enterprise Edition)?

Tags: overriding, url-rewriting, magento

How can we override/rewrite Enterprise class files/class (for Enterprise Edition of Magento)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it. It's similar to what we do with core files in Community Edition.

Just need to see the **config.xml** of any Enterprise core modules. They put "**enterprise**" in front.

Sample code to override **Enterprise_GiftRegistry** Block:-

```
<blocks>    
    <enterprise_giftregistry>
        <rewrite>
               <customer_list>MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_MyBlock</customer_list>
        </rewrite>
    </enterprise_giftregistry>
</blocks>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Be careful with your terminology there.  It's a common mistake (I've done it myself), but a class override is usually thought of as replace the class with a new one in app/code/local/Mage or app/code/local/Enterprise.  What you're talking about here is a class rewrite.

Comment: Did not know about that. I thought override and rewrite are same terminology in Magento.

Comment: I don't think it's official, just something I've been trying to enforce informally.  Both names get used for both techniques.